# Apply CSS Class With AngularJS Run Time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to applay css class on that row where MaxStockLevel Is greter than Balence
i had try this code

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in products | filter:productFilter">
  <!--<tr ng-class="{{i.MaxStockLevel > i.Balence ? 'danger' : 'danger'}} ">-->
  <tr class="ng-class : i.maxstocklevel > i.Balence">
    <td>{{i.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{i.MinStockLevel}}</td>
    <td>{{i.MaxStockLevel}}</td>
    <td>{{i.Balence}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off:

```
<tr ng-class="{ 'myCustomClass' : i.maxstocklevel > i.Balence }">
```

(Also, "Balence" is spelled "Balance")

Comment: Note, quotes are not necessary here, as it's just a JS map. You may find quotes helpful if you have dashes or other symbols in your class name.

Answer (score 1):

you should try the following line

```
<tr ng-class="{ 'YourClassName' : i.maxstocklevel > i.Balance }">
```

For more info about `ng-class` [click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-class` takes a JavaScript object which maps class names to booleans, like so:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Main', function($scope) {
  $scope.maxStockLevel = 50;
  
  $scope.items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    $scope.items.push({ stockLevel: Math.random() * 100 });
  }
});
```

```css
.danger { background: red; }
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main">
  <div ng-repeat="i in items" ng-class="{ danger: i.stockLevel > maxStockLevel }">
    Item {{ $index }}
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
```